# Laravel 5.1 seeding a new column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a database table called `locations` and I need to add a new `status` column.  I have setup the following migration file which adds the field fine when i run `php artisan migrate`, but how can I insert a value of `Active` for each row in the table?

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddStatusToLocationsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('locations', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->string('status')->after('email');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('locations', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->dropColumn('status');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your field to a default value

```
$table->string('status')->after('email')->default('active')
```

If you need to update just the current records, you can do with seeding:

run this artisan command:

```
php artisan make:seeder AddStatusSeeder
```

Then in your AddStatusSeeder:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class AddStatusSeeder extends Seeder
{
     /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function run()
     {
         DB::table('locations')->update([
            'status' => 'Active'
         ]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the above. Any ideas about how to modify the above when you want a unique ID? Currently when I generate a UUID the same ID populates each row with the same value. Code:  'public_id' => (string)Uuid::generate(4)

Comment: `DB::table('your-table')->update([...])` without a `where` condition means, it will update all records. You need to loop through all rows and update the UUID individually.

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions

You can totally add a value to your existing seeder for this table

You also can create a new seeder in which you fetch every location, add your new field value and save it like so

```
foreach(Location::all() as $location){
    $location->status = 'Active';
    $location->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [database seeding](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/seeding). You can either create a model for the locations table or use the `DB::table` way of inserting.

You can then run `php artisan migrate --seed` to create the schema and populate the DB.

Comment: Yes I already have a model for locations table and a seeder file.  But my question is, how do I seed a new column?